# KVM Ubuntu USB Passtrough

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu, usb, guest

I currently try to add a Hauppauge DVR Tuner (USB) to a KVM Machine. Both (Host and Guest) are running Ubuntu. 
This is my XML Guest File:

https://pastebin.com/gBvFhsXs

I already tried to follow this therad: [Mapping USB drive direct to libvirt KVM virtual machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/348983/mapping-usb-drive-direct-to-libvirt-kvm-virtual-machine)
and this thread:
[attaching usb dongle to KVM VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/666210/attaching-usb-dongle-to-kvm-vm)

My problem is that the attached USB devices are not shown by "lsusb" in my guest. But no error message appears at any time. The USB folder is owned by the KVM user.